# Como alinhar uma lista no cabeçalho de um site (HTML/CSS)

Tags: css, html5

Estou tendo dificuldades para alinhar uma lista(MENU) no cabeçalho. A lista fica embaixo, onde já acaba o backgroundcolor.

```
<div class="cabecalho">
        <div class="logo">
            <img align="right" src="Imagens/Logo.png">
            <h2 align="right">Nome Site</h2>
        </div>
        <ul type="none">
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="produtos.html">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="empresa.html">Empresa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

E no CSS está assim

```
.cabecalho{
    background-color:blanchedalmond;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

ul{
    display: flex; 
}

ul li{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul li a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Olá, a lista está aparecendo embaixo do div do cabeçalho porque a altura do `div` do cabeçalho está definida como `height: 50px;` e o tamanho da lista é maior que 50px.

Para resolver, só precisa aumentar a altura do `div` do cabeçalho para acomodar a lista.

```
.cabecalho {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* alterado para altura automática */
  display: flex; /* adicionado display flex */
  justify-content: space-between; /* adicionado para alinhar logo e lista */
  align-items: center; /* adicionado para centralizar verticalmente */
  padding: 10px 20px; /* adicionado espaçamento */
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo h2 {
  margin-left: 10px; /* adicionado margem para separar texto da imagem */
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```